# Fragment is not Covering the entire screen even the layout width and height is match parent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity and when I click on the "Register" TextView a fragment will open and in that fragment all the Registration detail is there.But when I click on the textview the Fragment is loaded successfully but it did'nt cover up the entire screen.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragments fragments=new Fragments();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment_Register,fragments);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    }
});
    }
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.attendance.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/blurbackgound"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:id="@+id/login_mobile_number"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Enter mobile number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="10"
         android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_local_phone_black_24dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:id="@+id/phonelogo"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mb_counter"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/login_mobile_number"
        android:text="abssh"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_mobile_number"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:text="Student"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/Radio_button_student"
            android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:text="Teacher"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/Radio_button_teacher"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SHOW"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/login_password"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/login_password"
        android:id="@+id/password_visibility"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/phonelogo"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        />


    <Button
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Login"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:background="@drawable/login_buttom"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FORGOT PASSWORD"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@id/login"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="|"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/forgot_password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@id/login"
        android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/Register"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Fragment_Register"></RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragments.java**

```
    package com.example.user.attendance;

    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup; 
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


    public class Fragments extends Fragment {

        Button Register_Cancel_fullname, Register_Cancel_email, Register_Cancel_phone,
                Register_Cancel_password, Sign_up,Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password;
        String  Passcode,Confirm_Passcode;
        EditText Full_Name, Email_Address, Phone_number, Password_register,Confirm_Password_register;
        CircleImageView Register_add_photo;
        LinearLayout select_photo_from_camera,select_photo_from_gallery;
        TextView textView,hint_textview_circular_image_view;
       // RadioButton Category_teacher,Category_student;
        RadioGroup Teacher_student;




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View myfragmentVieew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);

            //Edit Text
            Full_Name = (EditText) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_name_and_surname);
            Email_Address = (EditText) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Email_address);
            Phone_number = (EditText) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Phone);
            Password_register = (EditText) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Password);
            Confirm_Password_register=(EditText)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id
                    .Confirm_Password_Register);

            //Button
            Sign_up = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Signup);
            Register_Cancel_fullname = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_First_Cancel_Button);
            Register_Cancel_email = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Second_Cancel_Button);
            Register_Cancel_phone = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Third_Cancel_Button);
            Register_Cancel_password = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_fourth_Cancel_Button);
            Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password=(Button)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id
                    .Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password_Button);
            Register_add_photo=(CircleImageView)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_add_photo);

            //TextView
            textView = (TextView) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_textview);
            hint_textview_circular_image_view=(TextView)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id
                    .hint_of_image_view);

return myfragmentVieew;
}
}
```

**Here is what I am getting:**
[image: Here is what I am getting]

Comment: Remove android:padding="10dp" from root.

Comment: Damn,such a msitake....Well thnks it worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from root layout.

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

This will solve the problem.